# <iframe>'s Referer header does not change on Firefox with history.pushState

Tags: javascript, firefox, iframe, pushstate, http-referer

Here's an example (and a [**live demo**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/6tmk8mb4/5/show/), with a 2 second delay):

```
history.pushState({}, 'test', '/test');

$('<iframe src="http://example.com/' + (+new Date()) + '"></iframe>').appendTo('body');
$('<div><script src="/foo2"></' + 'script></div>').appendTo('body');
$('<img src="/foo3" />').appendTo('body');
```

If you look at the requests in Chrome, all have `Referer: http://example.com/test`. Firefox, however, does not change it in the request sent when the `<iframe>` is created.

I couldn't find anything in the spec about a browser should handle this, so is there any way to get Firefox to behave like Chrome (or forge the `Referer` header)?

Comment: There was a bug report filed six months ago: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=968861

Comment: In chome it was fixed: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=45361
Firefox stil didnt